# How to create multiple windows with a single index.html in electron.js

Tags: javascript, user-interface, electron

I am working on an electron desktop app and trying to understand how it works. I want to add different windows, but so far I couldn't understand how it can be done. I have been examining the source code of atom and github desktop app and they only have one single index.html. That's all.

How is it achieved to lots of different windows (or tabs) only with one html file?

Can someone explain or point a reference?

Thanks

Comment: This can be achieved using SPA framework like Angular.

Comment: @AnandG Any suggestions where I can find a related example? Please not the super complicated projects like atom.

Comment: @Rhayene not different main windows. Also not the "same" window within the same main process. Like in Slack or Github App, one window but different views.

Comment: http://electron.rocks/electron-angular-creating-sample-application/